# Angular UI Bootstrap Dropdown: Auto scroll to the selected value on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu with values from 0 to 50. When I open the page with a value saved - let's say 25 and click the dropdown the values shown in the dropdown are 0 1 2.... It should have automatically scrolled to 24 25 26 27 28.... But currently it does not.

```html
<div class="btn-group" dropdown="" dropdown-append-to-body is-open="hey" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="">{{selectedItem}}</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a data-ng-repeat="item in items"
               ng-click="itemSelected(item)"> {{item}} </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/np2017/bs7145v8/

Please suggest any possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it should scroll to the selected value? I don't recall ever seeing a dropdown menu with scrolling in the first place. Keep in mind that this isn't a selectbox.

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8gdbc8bv/1) showing something like you describe. One item is active. What would make it scroll?

Comment: I ask again, what makes you think it should be auto-scrolling without you programming it to do so? If you don't, you'll need to take a shot at doing that and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Well that precisely was my question wasn't it? Make it behave like a selectbox which auto scrolls to the value it contains.

Comment: "How do I do [something]?" is generally off-topic at SO. That's my point, and it's why your question hasn't received much attention. You have to try something first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i will try to come up with something then.

Comment: @npn did you managed to solve it? I have similar situation.

Comment: @Igor Dimchevski still an open question.

Comment: @npn I have changed it to html select tag, but check for some OS angularjs components that have the feature.